# Is code that's generated automatically by Visual Studio thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, thread-safety

I'm learning C#. Sorry for the newbie question.

This is part of some code that's automatically generated by Visual Studio 2015 when I start a Windows Forms project. It's in Form1.Designer.cs

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

I'm trying to see if I understand the concept of thread-safety correctly. Isn't it possible for `components` to be set to `null` between the time the `if` statement is evaluated and the time `components.Dispose()` is called?

Thanks in advance for any help understanding this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not thread-safe code. Your assumption is correct that `components` *could* become null between the check and the `Dispose`.

However, that doesn't mean it's bad code. Not all code needs to be thread-safe. If two threads were disposing the same object, it's very likely that *that* behaviour is a bug, rather than `Dispose` being erroneous.

Comment: Then I understood correctly! You've been a big help. Thank you. 

Comment: But does code need to be thread-safe if it's part of some API that's meant to be shared and implemented by third-party coders? Or would two threads disposing the same object still be considered a mistake on the part of the implementer rather than a flaw in the API? I could use a little more of your insight if that's all right.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Typically you only need to implement `IDisposable` if you have unmanaged resources you need to tidy up. It would be trivial to make the call 'thread-safe' in that a secondary call would do nothing (a simple flag check with `Interlocked`) - but that is more defensive coding rather than making it thread-safe. You'd have to define *what it means* to have the object dispose twice at the same time. I can't see a reason why two threads would both think they need to dispose an object - typically whoever *caused* the acquisition of unmanaged resources would be responsible for cleaning up.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Since it's your API, you can implement it however you want. I can't say there's any reason people would *assume* `Dispose` would be threadsafe - perhaps if your object was specifically used for threading (for example, a concurrent collection). This was a bit long-winded, but IMHO, no - you don't need to make it thread-safe. If you're worried about providing an API to third parties, you can either document the behaviour as explicitly not thread-safe or provide a thread-safe check to prevent dispose from executing more than once.

Comment: Really great help. Thank you so much!